# Finding if a given PC name exists on a network

Tags: networking, scripting

I have been given a network share address by my infra team, but it doesn't seem to come up when I address it. The address is supposed to contain code for a project build, which I need.

I have pinged the host but nothing comes up. I *think* this means that it doesn't exist, and the guys in infra must have misspelled it. They're in a different time zone, and I have five hours where I can't access these files which I need for a production release.

What I'd like to do is grep for the host address, finding all machines on the network with an address similar to the one given. Does anyone know of a tool or script which would facilitate this?

Thanks in advance.

Update: to be exact, this is a Windows network. I use the word Grep in its generic verbal sense. as in, to grep for something meaning some pattern recognition tool. apologies, I didn't really think the question through.

Really what I'm looking for is something like:

nslookup [^servernamestart*] or something like that. Does any such utility exist on Windows? I know it's a long shot...

Comment: Does not belong to StackOverflow. Anyway, with "name" you mean DNS name or Windows name?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you on a Unix machine? or a windows network? you mentioned Grep, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

try `nslookup [hostname]`

you could also try `nmap -sP [ip-start]-[ip-end]` to find alive hosts with similar ip addresses

dont really know what you mean by "grep for hostname"

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows Network with Windows OS, try this (from [Microsoft site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308887))

> Search for a computer when you do not know the name of the computer:
>
> 1. If you do not know the name of the computer, you can browse for
>      the
>      computer on the network:
> 2. Click Start, and then click My Network
>      Places.
> 3. Click Entire Network.
> 4. Double-click Microsoft Windows
>      Network.
> 5. Double-click the name of the domain that you want to
>      search.
> 6. Double-click the name of the computer that you want to
>      access so that the shared resources are displayed.